# is the session hash in rails depending on the user's browser settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

my rails app provides additional data through the session hash. 
while testing it in different browsers - including ff 3.5, safari 4 and [iCab](http://www.icab.de/) (which i am using because of its harsh security guidelines) - i found out that even in the app's log the session hash looked different - the only thing the iCab session contained was the session_id
and nothing else.
Does it make sense to disallow session_variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like iCab is blocking cookies. Rails is generating you a new session_id for each request but all other data stored in the session is not available between requests.

Comment: thx mike,
that was my first thought - but in the preferences i explicitly allowed the session\_cookies - what the hack is this option for then?

Comment: there is no difference between allowing and not allowing session_cookies - ok, this is a very product specific question<br />
thank you!